# Can I run TalkBack and my custom accessibility service at the same time?

Tags: android, accessibility, talkback

Tell me please. I have developed my own accessibility service, can I run it at the same time as TalkBack?

If I start my service and TalkBack at the same time, but in this case my service stops working

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, in fact, I [made one myself](https://github.com/qbalsdon/accessibility_broadcast_dev) - my service required TalkBack to be on and wouldn't perform functions without it:

```
        // These are the two most popular ones, but Amazon has their own version too!
        val TALKBACK_PACKAGE_NAMES = listOf(
            "com.google.android.marvin.talkback/com.google.android.marvin.talkback.TalkBackService",
            "com.samsung.android.accessibility.talkback/com.samsung.android.marvin.talkback.TalkBackService"
        )
        ...
        if (TALKBACK_PACKAGE_NAMES.intersect(
                Settings
                    .Secure
                    .getString(
                        context.contentResolver,
                        Settings.Secure.ENABLED_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICES
                    ).split(":").toSet()
            ).isEmpty()
        ) {
            log("AccessibilityActionReceiver", "TalkBack needs to be running.")
            return
        }
```

A simpler way to check could be:

```
val am = getSystemService(Context.ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE) as AccessibilityManager
val isTalkBackEnabled = am.isEnabled && am.isTouchExplorationEnabled
```

However this doesn't work for me as I required the specific gestures and features of TalkBack itself. This checks if the user is using a screen reader with "touch exploration" (which is by default on, but can be turned off by certain users). Each solution has complications, I guess.

To diagnose your problem, I recommend using

```
adb shell settings get secure enabled_accessibility_services
```

1. Turn your service on, and confirm that the above command has your package and service name in it
2. Turn TalkBack on, and confirm that both your package and service is there as well as TalkBack

If at any point you don't see what you expect, check your logcat for crashes.